# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fileds Accordion JS, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently developing an accordion with Advanced Custom Fields on WordPress.

I'm really new to PHP and JS coding and basically have done all of it following tutorials and learning as fast as I can.

I have managed to make a functional accordion, but there is one little problem: I don't know how to make it to have the first tab open by default and to automatically close a tab when another is opened.

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
/*renders the ACF and has the html structure of the Acordion*/

            <?php the_field(main_content); ?>               

                     <?php if(have_rows('tabs')) ?>

                    <div id="acordion">
                        <?php while(have_rows('tabs')): the_row(); ?>
                       <button class="accordion"><a href="#tab-content--<php $tabLabel++; ?>"><h4 class="tabheadername"><?php the_sub_field('tab_label'); ?></h4></a><h4 class="tabheadercompany"><?php the_sub_field('company')?></h4></button>

                        <div class="panel">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('tab_image'); ?>" alt="" style="position:relative; z-index:500;" class="png" />
                        <?php the_sub_field('tab_content'); ?>


                        </div>
                    </div>                         


                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**This is the CSS to style it:**

```
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd; 
}


button.accordion:after {
content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
font-size: 13px;
color: #777;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

div.panel {
padding: 5px 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
opacity: 1;
max-height: 500px; /* Whatever you like, as long as its more than the height                     of the content (on all screen sizes) */
padding-top:20px!important;
}




h4.tabheadername {
display: inline;
}

h4.tabheadercompany {
display: inline; color:#333!important; margin-left:7px!important;border-       left: 1px solid #333; padding-left:7px!important;
}


#acordion:first_child {
opacity: 1!important;
max-height: 500px; /* Whatever you like, as long as its more than the height  of the content (on all screen sizes) */
padding-top:20px!important;
}


/*----- Accordion -----*/
.accordion, .accordion * {
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
box-sizing:border-box;
 }

.accordion {
overflow:hidden;
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
border-radius:3px;
background:#f7f7f7;
}

/*----- Section Titles -----*/
.accordion-section-title {
width:100%;
padding:15px;
display:inline-block;
border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;
background:#333;
transition:all linear 0.15s;
/* Type */
font-size:1.200em;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
color:#fff;
}

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
 background:#4c4c4c;
    /* Type */
text-decoration:none;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
border-bottom:none;
}

 /*----- Section Content -----*/
.accordion-section-content {
padding:15px;
display:none;
}
```

**And this is the JS script:**

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here is how my tabs look (they are closed by default):**

[image: Here is how my tabs look (they are closed by default)]

I would like to know how to make it to have the first tab open by default and to automatically close open tabs when another one is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a php count variable to count each returned element. You can achieve this in your code like this:

```
<?php the_field(main_content); ?>               

<?php 
$count = 0; //setup the count parameter
if(have_rows('tabs')) 
?>
<div id="acordion">
<?php while(have_rows('tabs')): the_row(); $count++; //loop through returned items ?>
<button class="accordion">
<a href="#tab-content--<?php $tabLabel++; ?>" <?php if($count == 1){ echo 'class="active"'; } //add the 'active' class if it is the first item ?>"><h4 class="tabheadername"><?php the_sub_field('tab_label'); ?></h4></a><h4 class="tabheadercompany"><?php the_sub_field('company')?></h4>
</button>
<div class="panel">
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('tab_image'); ?>" alt="" style="position:relative; z-index:500;" class="png" />
<?php the_sub_field('tab_content'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code above basically sets up a variable to count each item that is returned. Then checks for the first item and sets the tab class to "active". Hope this helps, please let me know if this works for you.